# Meaning of "data_coding" field in SMPP

Tags: encoding, sms, decoding, smpp

What is the meaning of **"data_coding"** field in the [SMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer) protocol?

I searched for this but couldn't find any helpful resource.

Comment: _As a side note:_ the number one source of information in such cases is the **specification**: [_SMPP Protocol Specification v3.4_](http://opensmpp.org/specs/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) and [_SMPP Protocol Specification v5.0_](http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv50.pdf)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In short, datacoding contains the information on how the text in an smpp 
SubmitSM (i.e. a typical SMS message) message is encoded. The SubmitSM packet 
contains a binary encoded body, and the dataCoding is how the text is stored 
in this body.

The most important values are:

- **00000000** (0) - usually [GSM7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) (the default 7 bit encoding for messages, with a few characters that are encoded as two bytes), but technically could be something else
- **00000011** (3) for standard ISO-8859-1
- **00001000** (8) for the universal character set -- de facto UTF-16

Other possible values (rarely used):

- **00000001** - IA5_CCITT_T_50_ASCII_ANSI_X3_4
- **00000010** - OCTET_UNSPECIFIED_8BIT_BINARY_1
- **00000100** - OCTET_UNSPECIFIED_8BIT_BINARY_2
- **00000101** - JIS_X_02081990
- **00000110** - CYRLLIC_ISO88595
- **00000111** - LATIN_HEBREW_ISO88598
- **00001001** - PICTOGRAM_ENCODING
- **00001010** - ISO2022JP_MUSIC_CODES
- **00001101** - EXTENDED_KANJI_JISX_02121990
- **00001110** - KS_C_5601

And two reserved for special uses:

- **00001011** - RESERVED #1
- **00001100** - RESERVED #2

In short, if your binary body is unicode (UTF-16) you will set dataCoding to 8. If your message is stored as GSM7 then it will (usually) be 0.

Comment: Actually data coding 0x00 in SMPP means 'SMSC Default Alphabet' which is *usually* GSM7, but technically could be something else

Comment: Is there any article or any other reference for that ?

Comment: @PrasadWeera not an easy read, but my knowledge comes from http://www.scribd.com/doc/64970163/SMPP-v3-4-Issue1-2 (SMPP specification).

Answer (score 0):

It means how text is converted into bytes, since SMPP is a binary protocol but applications typically deal with text strings. The first hit on google for 'smpp data coding' explains it well http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smstools/raw-attachment/wiki/MiscWikiFiles/smppv34_gsmumts_ig_v10.pdf in section 2.2.2.

Comment: Then what is the difference between encoding(like using UTF-8) and data coding ?

Comment: Data coding means the same as encoding.

Comment: I'm using smpp Connector with an additional parameter for passing the data coding. When I asked about that, I was told that it represents if the content is binary or text or flash... Can you please explain that ?

Comment: I read that post but still got the issue. here in this post [link](http://www.telecomspace.com/smsforum.net_archive/smf/index00d0.html?topic=1257.0), they are talking about a **data coding**. That's what I don't get.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely help:
[ETSI GSM 03.38 Specification](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/03/0338/05.00.00_60/gsmts_0338v050000p.pdf)