# Perl issue when encoding mysql data from UTF-8 to UCS-2 for SMPP

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding, smpp, ucs2

I am trying to fetch UTF-8 accentuated characters "é" "ê" from mysql and convert them to UCS-2 when sending over SMPP. The data is stored as utf8_general_ci and I perform the following when opening the DB connection:

```
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'}=1;
$dbh->do("set NAMES 'utf8'");
```

If I test the sending part by hard coding the string value with "é" "ê" using data_encoding=8, it goes through perfectly. However if I comment out the first line and just use what comes from the DB, it fails. Also, if I try to send the characters using the DB and setting data_encoding=3, it also works fine, but then the "ê" would not appear, which is also expected. Here is what I use:

```
$fred = 'éêcole'; <-- If I comment out this line, the SMPP call fails
$fred = decode('utf-8', $fred);
$fred = encode('UCS-2', $fred);

$resp_pdu = $short_smpp->submit_sm(
        source_addr_ton => 0x00,
        source_addr_npi => 0x01,
        source_addr => $didnb,
        dest_addr_ton => 0x01,
        dest_addr_npi => 0x01,
        destination_addr => $number,
        data_coding => 0x08,
        short_message => $fred
) or do {
        Log("ERROR: submit_sm indicated error: " . $resp_pdu->explain_status());
        $success = 0;
};
```

The different values for the data_coding fields are the following:
[Meaning of "data_coding" field in SMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985088/meaning-of-data-coding-field-in-smpp)

```
00000000 (0) - usually GSM7
00000011 (3) for standard ISO-8859-1
00001000 (8) for the universal character set -- de facto UTF-16
```

The SMPP provider's documentation also mentions that special characters should be handled via UCS-2:
https://community.sinch.com/t5/SMS-365-enterprise-service/Handling-Special-Characters/ta-p/1137

How should I prepare the data that is coming out of the DB to make this SMPP call work?

I am using Perl v5.10.1

Thanks !

Comment: The `decode('utf-8', $fred)` looks suspicious to me. Isn't the point of `$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'}=1;` to decode the returned values? If so, the fix is to remove `$fred = decode('utf-8', $fred);`. And if so, your working program works because it's encoded using UTF-8 but you implicitly told Perl it was encoded using ASCII by not using `use utf8;`.

Comment: Please provide `sprintf "%vX", $s` for a working value and a failing value (from before the decode/encode). If I'm right in the previous comment, you will see code points (E9 for é) when it fails, and a string encoded using UTF-9 (C3 A9 for é IIRC) when it succeeds.

Comment: So when I use the stored value and print the sprintf just before the encode/decode, this is what I get: E9.EA.63.6F.6C.65, so you are right. Then if I remove the decode utf-8 part and only leave the encode ucs-2, I now get "é cole", the ê is missing. Then if I add use utf8; at the top, I get the same result.

Comment: So if I add use utf8; the output before the encode ucs-2 is E9.EA.63.6F.6C.65 and once the encode is done, the output becomes 0.E9.0.EA.0.63.0.6F.0.6C.0.65

Comment: If I leave the use utf-8 at the top, and decode utf8, the output right after the decode is FFFD.FFFD.63.6F.6C.65 and once encoded back to ucs-2 the output is FF.FD.FF.FD.0.63.0.6F.0.6C.0.65

Comment: The messages dont fail anymore although they dont come out right. I believe this was due to me having a too long messages once encoded. They now are submitting correctly when only using 'éêcole' but the issue remains, the accents are missing.

Comment: FFFD is the replacement character, signaling an error.

Comment: `0.E9.0.EA.0.63.0.6F.0.6C.0.65` is correct UCS-2be for `éêcole`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;` is used to decode the values returned from the database, causing queries to return decoded text (strings of Unicode Code Points). It makes no sense to decode such a string. Go straight to the `encode`.

```perl
my $s_ucp = "\xE9\xEA\x63\x6F\x6C\x65";  # éêcole
# -or-
use utf8; # Script is encoded using UTF-8.
my $s_ucp = "éêcole";

printf "%vX\n", $s_ucp;                  # E9.EA.63.6F.6C.65

my $s_ucs2be = encode('UCS-2', $s_ucp);

printf "%vX\n", $s_ucs2be;               # 0.E9.0.EA.0.63.0.6F.0.6C.0.65
```

Comment: Ok, I apparently dont really understand how they all interact together, thanks for the explanations. So if I comment out $dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'}=1; and $dbh->do("set NAMES 'utf8'"); IT NOW WORKS !! If I could I would send you 12 beers :)  I just spent two days on this. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this.

Comment: So I really thought that $dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1 would somehow make sure that the utf-8 data is to be assigned as utf-8 in the perl variable, like telling explicitly to perl which encoding is the data encoded with

Comment: Re "*would somehow make sure that the utf-8 data is to be assigned as utf-8 in the perl variable*",  `set NAMES 'utf8'` sets how it's encoded over the wire. `$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'}=1;` *decodes* from UTF-8. `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` passed to `connect` does both.

Answer (score 0):

`SET NAMES` says the encoding you have/want in the *client*.  That is, regardless of the encoding in the table, MySQL will convert it to whatever `SET NAMES` says during a `SELECT`.

So, feed what comes from the `SELECT` directly to SMPP.  (It won't be readable by most other clients.)

```
SET NAMES ucs2
```

(The collation is irrelevant to the encoding.)

You could ask the `SELECT` to convert with something like

```
CONVERT(col_name, CHAR UNICODE)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html